# Celery and ha rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I developing application where celery with rabbitmq as backend are core modules. Does celery support use case when exist several rabbitmq nodes and when one node goes down celery switch to another node? What the best option to handle cases when rabbitmq is down in order to archive high availability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no HA features in celery by itself. Instead, you can use [HA proxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)+RabbitMQ for load balancing with fault detection. For more information you can see this:

- http://www.joshdevins.net/2010/04/16/rabbitmq-ha-testing-with-haproxy/
- http://www.sebastien-han.fr/blog/2012/05/21/openstack-high-availability-rabbitmq/
- [http://www.amazon.com/RabbitMQ-Action-Distributed-Messaging-Everyone/dp/1935182978](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182978) - chapter 5: Clustering and dealing with failure